# Improve Mysql query performance

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this high scores table

> `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`highscores`(`
>   lid`int(11) NOT NULL,`
>   username`varchar(50) NOT NULL,`
>   userid`int(6) NOT NULL,`
>   score`int(16) NOT NULL,`
>   dateadded`timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>     PRIMARY KEY  (`lid`,`username`),
>     KEY`score`(`lid`,`score`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

and it has just over 2 million rows. When I run the following query it takes about 4.5 seconds. I'm hoping  someone here has some advice on how I  can improve the speed, by changing the query, adding/ modifying indexes, or maybe changing the storage engine?

> SELECT
>      h.userid,h.username AS user ,count(h.username) AS scorecount
>     FROM
>       highscores h INNER JOIN
>       (select lid, min(score) AS maxscore
>        FROM highscores group by lid) t on h.lid = t.lid and h.score = t.maxscore
>   group by h.username ORDER BY scorecount  DESC

as requested here is the EXPLAIN:
[image: EXPLAIN]

Comment: Why do you have `min(score) AS maxscore`?   This causes something called "cognitive dissonance".  You are calling a minimum a maximum.

Comment: Start by looking at what `EXPLAIN` tells you about your statement …

Comment: I have min(score) AS maxscore because I reused the query from another game where Higher scores are better.  Just lazyness/oversight on my part. For clarity I will change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I Ended up doing was Caching the query, having it update every 10 min.  There may be a better solution, but I could not get the query to  be any faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT h.userid, h.username AS user, count(h.username) AS scorecount
FROM highscores h INNER JOIN
     (select lid, min(score) AS maxscore
      FROM highscores
      group by lid
     ) t
     on h.lid = t.lid and h.score = t.maxscore
group by h.username
ORDER BY scorecount DESC;
```

This seems to be answering the question:  "How many times does a user have the maximum (or minimum) score in the table?".  This suggests that you can rewrite the query as:

```
select hs.userid, hs.username, count(*) as scorecount
from highscores hs
where not exists (select 1 from highscores hs2 where hs2.lid = hs.lid and hs2.score > hs.score)
group by hs.userid, hs.username
order by scorecount desc;
```

Your existing indexes should work well on this.  An index on `userid, username` would help some database engines, but I don't think MySQL would take advantage of it.

Comment: sadly your new query took 181.7252 sec, I does perform the same results, though

Comment: Do you know that only one user has the top score for any given `lid`?

Comment: it is possible to tie or have the same score

Answer (score -1):

sir, i dont think adjusting your query is your right solution here. you just said you had 2 million rows in that score table. can you imagine how long it would take for your queries to check cells/rows of each row whenever you execute them?

what you need is database normalization and proper way of designing your tables

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Im really not sure how to go about normalizing the table any further.

Comment: can you add the schema of the other tables you used there? so we can figure out what we can do with them.. you might want to separate the scores from minimum ones to the maximum ones.

Comment: well, lid is "level id"(an int(6)), as in the level the user got the score in. each level has its own leaderboard, as well as a global leaderboard. I also have a standard  users table  where all the users info is stored. I  chose to store both the users id(uid) and username in the highscores table to try and keep the querys somewhat simpler.